# How does JavaScript compare strings which contain digits?

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain how does JS compare alphanumeric strings? For ex. why the following returns me 'false' when I run it in browser console:

```
'abc' > 'abc.15' // false
```

And why this returns 'true':

```
'abcd' > 'abc.15' // true
```

Comment: not sure if we can apply > on strings?

Comment: @RamSingh, you can.

Comment: Yes he can. It does string comparison and  `.` is greater than nothing and `d` is >  than `.` - also `"10"` is < `"9"`

Comment: Try to read ECMAScript spec. It's hard, but it has all the answers if you can get through it. If it's too hard, read Speaking Javascript which is basically spec translated to human language.

Comment: In this case, [the spec leads here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), with the nitty gritty [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison).  A good starting point is the MDN page for whatever you're interested in, as they [tend to have links direct to the relevant part of the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?v=control#Specifications).